# Run-Time Error '91' Object Variable or with block variable not set

Tags: vb6, runtime

I have created a simple VB 6.0 program to calculate day-to-day sales. I have converted this project into an .exe file where other users can run this program in their terminal to work with, but when they run this exe file they get above mentioned runtime error. Can anyone tell me how to overcome this error?

```
Dim myobject As Object

Private Sub Command1_Click()
    Set myobject = Nothing
    Adodc1.Recordset.AddNew
End Sub

Private Sub Command2_Click()
    Adodc1.Recordset.Update
    MsgBox "Your Record Updated Successfully!!", vbInformation 
End Sub 

Private Sub Command3_Click() 
    Text19.Text = Val(Text11) + Val(Text12) + Val(Text13) + Val(Text14) + Val(Text15) 
End Sub
```

Comment: You'll need to get a clear and precise description of what the user does just before it happens and then emulate those actions in the IDE and fix the bug.  The code is using an object which is not, or is no longer, valid.

Comment: Can you please explain it to me in coding?

Comment: can you post the related code of your program?

Comment: Dim myobject As Object

Private Sub Command1_Click()
Set myobject = Nothing
Adodc1.Recordset.AddNew
End Sub

Private Sub Command2_Click()
Adodc1.Recordset.Update
MsgBox "Your Record Updated Successfully!!", vbInformation
End Sub

Private Sub Command3_Click()
Text19.Text = Val(Text11) + Val(Text12) + Val(Text13) + Val(Text14) + Val(Text15)
End Sub

Comment: I moved your code to the question. Which line does it fail on?

Comment: there is no wrong in the coding but when i run the exe file in another machine it gives me runtime error